# Nested views in a view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

How can I show the attendances that belong to each event under each event?

Event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
```

Events/index:

```
%h1 Listing events
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Starts at
      %th Duration

  %tbody
    - @events.each do |event|
      %tr
        %td= event.starts_at
        %td= event.duration

%br
```

I tried this code, but it renders totally all attendances under each event:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Starts at
      %th Duration

  %tbody
    - @events.each do |event|
      %tr
        %td= event.starts_at
        %td= event.duration
        - @attendances.each do |attendance|
          %tr
            %td= attendance.guest
            %td= attendance.attendance_rate
            %td= attendance.event
%br
```

It looks like I must change something in the array & in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have defined an association that dictates that an "event has many attendances", you may access those attendance records from the event record itself.

Something along the lines of the following should suffice:

```
%tbody
  - @events.each do |event|
    %tr
      %td= event.starts_at
      %td= event.duration
      - event.attendances.each do |attendance|
        %tr
          %td= attendance.guest
          %td= attendance.attendance_rate
          %td= attendance.event
```

By accessing the attendances through the `event` itself, you do not end up with all the extra attendances records (you only get the ones that are associated with the currently accessed event).

Comment: I know that I can access them in event/show by typing `@attendances = @event.attendances` for the show controller. The point is that I want to see all the attendances in the event/index view.inside the table